# Testing series for absolute convergence

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {3^{1+3n}}{n^n}$$

Determine if the series converges absolutely or not.
I know it does, but when i apply the ratio test it gets a little messy, is that the only way?

Comment: The denominator is larger than $2^n$.  This could be useful

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Use the root test, then the denominator becomes $n$ and the numerator will be very close to $3^3 = 27$. The fraction $27/n$ should be more manageable.

Comment: Using the root test, how would i factor out n from the numerator?

Comment: Oh wait, would we get:
$$ 3(3/n)^n$$
then applying the root test, we get lim n→ infinity = 0 < 1, thus converges absolutely?

Comment: $a_n^{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{3^{\frac{1}{n}+3} }{n}$. The numerator is basically 27 for very large $n$, while the denominator goes to infinity. $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3^{\frac{1}{n}+3} }{n} = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Comparison with the sum of $\dfrac{3^{1+3n}}{n!}$ will give you the answer instantly.

Comment: Maybe "let you use the ratio test" is slightly better than "instantly". I still don't understand why this was flagged and downvoted.

Comment: I took the convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3^{1+3n}}{n!}$ to be something already known to anyone who does this kind of problem, since it's the natural exponential function.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
a_n = \frac {3^{1+3n}}{n^n}
$$
Using the ratio test,
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{\frac {3^{1+3(n+1)}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{\frac {3^{1+3n}}{n^n}}=\frac{27n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}
$$
And
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{27n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\le \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{27n^n}{n^{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{27}{n} = 0
$$
Thus the series converges.